# Click Base64 images in HTML to zoom up the image?

Tags: php, html

This is my coding. I can show the image but I want to click the image to zoom up or pop up the image.

```
<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['images'] ).'">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['images'] ).'" class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
```

When I click on the image there is no response or pop up, how can I do? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add more information to the question. What were you trying to do? Do you have a js code where you are trying to open an image in a popup?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by toggling a class on the image (or on a wrapper div) when the image is clicked. The added class (`.zoomed` in the snippet) is responsible for enlarging the image. The CSS in the example below is basic - but I hope it shows the idea and you can extend upon it!

```js
const image = document.querySelector('.thumbnail');

image.onclick = () => image.classList.toggle('zoomed');
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.zoomed {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="thumbnail" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for providing me this idea. I try to run my coding with your idea, but the image onclick still not function. How can I improve?

Comment: Would you mind updating your code above and I'll take a look?